# SubString from existing string iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have two strings as followed:

```
NSString *newStr = @"143.2a";
NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]{0,10})?)?$";
```

I want to substring "newStr" such as all my characters in "expression" should be present after subString. Like

```
NSString * extractedString = @"143.2";
```

(except all alphabets and symbols other than single'.')

How shall I do this?

Comment: The second string is a regex pattern. Add an example with an expected result.

Comment: Remove the "^" and the $" of your expression. Create a NSRegularExpression with this expression, call `rangeOfFirstMatchInString:options:range:` with the whole string range. Check if the returned `range`,  `range.location != 0`. If yes, you can substring on that range and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your regex pattern won't extract that string.

If you want to check for *one or more digits followed be a dot followed be one or more digits* the pattern is supposed to be

```
NSString *expression = @"\\d+\\.\\d+";
```

To extract the string use the `NSRegularExpression` class as suggested by Larme.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *firstMatch = [regex firstMatchInString:newStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, newStr.length)];
if (firstMatch) {
    NSString *extractedString = [newStr substringWithRange:firstMatch.range];
    NSLog(@"%@", extractedString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```